# How to use "named_struct" function programatically using SparkSQL with Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm looking for a way how to aggregate data using SparkSQL in Java by using an equivalent of `collect_list` (there is a built-in function for this one) and `named_struct` functions. Here is SQL query that copy the behaviour of what I'm trying to get:

```
select 
          group,
          named_struct(
          "mode", "action",
          "consent", "email",
          "input", collect_list(
             named_struct( 
               "id", id,
               "name", name 
               )
            ) 
          )                  data
          from previous
          group by group
          order by group
```

`collect_list` aggregate structs by `group` field.
There is one objection to the above query fields in the `named_struct` functions can be dynamically selected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: let me check out, maybe I can help you with

Comment: why don't you try to run that sentence is SQL context of spark?

Comment: I can't have it hardcoded because end-user could potentially change the schema of this, but the aggregate should work in the same way.

Comment: ok, i understand!!